# Spaces are appearing above and below images in HTML email

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I'm seeing gaps above and below two images in a 3 column 1 row table. There is text in the middle column and two images either side in the adjacent columns. Here is how it looks and the code in question. I've tried the `style="display:block"` and border collapse as suggested on here but both have no effect. Can anyone please advise?

Here is the problem:

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/2gwwby8/8]

Here is the code:

```
   <table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="25"><tr><td height="25" colspan="4"><img src="images/South-West-Email-vz2_09.jpg" width="600" height="25" alt="Boarder" /></td></tr></table><table width="600" height="261" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top" width="32" height="261"><img style="display: block;margin-bottom:0" src="images/South-West-Email-v2_06.jpg" width="32" height="261" alt="boarder" /></td><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="Content" width="355" align="left" height="0" valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 3px; padding-top: 8px;"><span class="Devname" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; color: #257847; line-height: 17px;">Ilfracombe- Lantern Court </span><br /><span class="beds" style="font-size: 15px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 18px;">1 bedroom at £230,000 (2 remaining)<br />2 bedroom at £310,000 (1 remaining)</span><br/><br/><span class="Devdescript" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px;">Boasting a cliff top location with stunning views of Ilfracombe Harbour, Lantern Court is a beautiful, contemporary Retirement Living development of 42 one and two bedroom apartments.</span><br/><br/><span class="Devdescript" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 12px;">Lantern Court was 'highly commended' in the best retirement scheme category at the Housebuilder Awards 2012. Lantern Court is a truly iconic new development, well located on the historic harbour of Ilfracombe.</span></td><td valign="top" width="213" height="261"><a href="http://www.mccarthyandstone.co.uk/retirement-properties-for-sale/lantern-court-ilfracombe/?utm_source=mccarthyandstone&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_content=south_west_september&amp;utm_campaign=email " style="color: #277A4B; text-decoration: none;"><img  style="display:block; margin-bottom:0" src="images/South-Wezxst-Email-v2_12.jpg" alt="Move For Free" width="213" height="261" border="0" /></a></td></tr></table><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td height="25" colspan="4"><img style="display: block;" src="images/South-Wezxst-Email-v2_13.jpg" width="600" height="25" alt="boarder" /></td></tr></table>
```

And my CSS:

```
<style type="text/css"> a:visited {text-decoration: none;} a:hover {text-decoration: underline;} a:active {text-decoration: none;} body,td,th {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;} table{border-collapse: collapse;} td{border:none;}</style>
```

Comment: Try adding `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table css.eg: `table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}`

Comment: ok,,is this a live site???if so plesae give the link..

Comment: Hi Lal, thank you for taking the time to help me .It is a HTML email not a live website. So is rendering this way in certain email clients (Outlook 2007).

Comment: check the edited answer please/..please try it..

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem can be solved using `border-collapse` CSS property.This sets the collapsing borders model for a table.

So, in your CSS add this

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    border:none;
}
```

Try it..

**EDIT**

### Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/prgmgkwy/)

Kindly add a style `vertical-align: bottom;` to your image.

that is

```
img
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked. The same spaces are appearing

Comment: Thanks for this Lal, the spaces are gone from the bottom of the images but remain at the top unfortunately. Do you have any further help? Thank you. http://tinypic.com/r/rbilmv/8

Comment: it is really difficult to find the problem from that image..if you can, please add the html codes to the question or as a fiddle..please..

Comment: Hi Lal, thank you for spending the time on this with me. Your help is much appreciated! I have added the code to my original question. I hope this helps! Thank you again.

Comment: Check my edited answer @Aliinwonderland ..I've tried it in a fiddle and it works..

Comment: Hi Lal, thanks for this. It does seem to work in fiddle but again, Litmus is displaying outlook 07 to render it with the space above the images: http://tinypic.com/r/2dgqog7/8